# How to pass URL query string parameters with requests

Tags: python, python-requests

The URL that I need to GET from looks something like this:

`https://example.com//report.php?file=MyFile&params=query=QueryMyFile^SomeParam=x^SomeOtherParam=y^AnotherOne=z`

I want to use `requests` to pass the params; something along the lines of:

```
base_url = 'https://example.com//report.php'
params = 
{ 'SomeParam': x,
  'SomeOtherParam': y,
  'AnotherOne': z
}

my_file = requests.get(base_url, params=params)
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're accepting them all in *one* query called "params".

That's a non-standard way to send params, so, there's no built-in way to do that with `requests`.  You'll have to join the keys and values with `'^'` character manually.

Comment: Hmm, that sucks. What about using `urllib`?

Comment: Not even `urllib.parse.urlencode()` will help here, since you can't specify a different separator.

Comment: Nope.  Blame whoever designed the `report.php`.

Comment: You should be able to mash the parameters together in the url in the format you need, and then just use requests to 'get' that url.

Comment: @SuperStew that is already what I am doing; I was looking for a more formal/standard way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

From the requests [docs](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/)..

```
payload = {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}
r = requests.get('http://httpbin.org/get', params=payload)
```

Answer (score 0):

The structure of your params data is in json style, i would also try to do it this way instead:

```
    import json
    import requests

    params = { 'SomeParam': x,
    'SomeOtherParam': y,
    'AnotherOne': z }

    params = json.dumps(params, separators=('^', '='))
    params = params[1:-1] #remove first and last curly brackets
    my_file = requests.get(base_url+params)
```

Something like that would do.